# Mapbox with Angular 6. "map container not found" error

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am developing my first angular web app and I want to introduce something similar to Google maps. I dón´t want to use this last one because of new billing politics, so I have tried MapBox.

Following the tutorial, I managed to create the map I need; the problem is, I don´t know how to display it on an angular component.

I generated this file for the map, and works perfectly with the browser and when I paste it directly on the index.html of my angular project. But when I try to use it on a component, I don´t know how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Points on a map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.47.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.47.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id='map'></div>
      <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'myToken'; // replace this with your access token
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'my style URL', // replace this with your style URL
        center: [-2.8662684, 43.2806562],
        zoom: 15
});
// code from the next step will go here

        map.on('click', function(e) {
          var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
          layers: ['rhynux'] // replace this with the name of the layer
      });

        if (!features.length) {
          return;
         }

      var feature = features[0];

      var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, -15] })
.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
.setHTML('<h3>' + feature.properties.title +      '</h3><p>' + feature.properties.description +     '</p>')
.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(map);
    });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I moved `<div id="map"></div>` to the component; but error is thrown "map container not found".

I also tried to install some nom packages like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-mapbox) but it has not enough information on how to use it for newbies like me.

[This another one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mapbox-gl) has no documentation either...

And I looked on several SO posts but found no understanding on how to do it.

Thanks. Your help is very appreciated

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and resolved it by using @ViewChild to locate the map element. Here's a bare-bones Angular component that will show a Mapbox map.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  template: '<div #mapElement style="height:200px"></div>'
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

    map: mapboxgl.Map;
    @ViewChild('mapElement') mapElement: ElementRef;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE';
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: this.mapElement.nativeElement,
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'
        });
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue, so I just added a `setTimeOut` to the method:

```js
Oninit(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    
  let mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<key>', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
  }).addTo(mymap);
  }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it turned out that I had put an empty space in the id attribute like this: id="map "